# Click button from method that is outside the oncreate in Android

Tags: android

The following is a basic striped down overview of one of my projects. I would like for a method outside of the oncreate to be able to click a button that is declaired in the oncreate but i cannot figure out how.

Here is my code: I would like to be able to `performClick()` the `webButton` from the method `clickButton()` but it does not work. If that is not possible i would atleast like to know how to start the intent that is trying to be started when the button is clicked from instide the `clickButton()` method.

Thank you in advance!!

```
public class cphome extends Activity {
    static final int check =111;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         final Button webButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        webButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), web.class);
                  startActivity(myIntent);
              }

            });





    }
    public void clickbutton(){
        webButton.performClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is that not working? Have you tried to debug int `onClick(View view)` when you call `clickbutton()`?

Comment: Why don't you make a `webButton` field of your class instead of variable in `onCreate` method?

Comment: I tried what you said Knickedi but i get the error "webButton cannot be resolved"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really strange pattern. I would suggest you to do something like that instead:

```
public class cphome extends Activity {
    static final int check =111;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         final Button webButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        webButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  performClickAction();
              }
            });

    }

    public void performClickAction(){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, web.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but then i get the error from "view" in the new Intent that "view cannot be resolved"

Comment: My fault. `view.getContext()` makes no sense any more (I truely hope you understand why). That happens if you copy & paste ;-). I updated `performClickAction`.